# How to limit the database records that are displayed in webpage using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have to retrieve the more than 100 records from the Database table using JSP. So, i want to control those database records into 10 records per page and each page will have the next and previous buttons contains link for these Pagination.

So, is there any tool available for pagination in JSP?

Please Guide me get out of this issue?

Comment: I would read all the 100 records into an object (that you'll create) and display the "lines" you want according to a page POST parameter that you'll pass from the JSP to itself.

Comment: if you have heaps of records you might be better off with pagination which impacts your sql to only fetch the rows you want. if youre using oracle you can use rownum to choose which rows you want to return.

Comment: @Venk: we are using oracle 9i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.ittreats.com/sun/java/pagination-using-jsp.html. This is a custom taglib that may help.

Answer (score 1):

pagination is about the ability of database engine to limit how many records to be returned in one time query execution.
for example, in mySQL, you should try to execute query with 'LIMIT' and 'OFFSET' clauses in it, like:
"SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0" means, "retrieves 10 records from table post started from the very first record (index number 0)",.
for full information about the LIMIT, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html

then you also need to display it in a convenience view, in a link like www.siteame.com/posts.jsp?p=2,.
if user access that link, your servlet should process it this way:
i assume that the number of posts is 100, the posts to be retrieved is 10, then the OFFSET should be (10 x (2 - 1)) (the p=2, or the second page). as the result your query should be "SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10", make sure that the OFFSET value is less than the number of your posts,.